# Unexpected module 'NgAutoCompleteModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular5, angular2-template

I am trying to implement autocomplete feature in my angular 2/4+ project.
I have tried a number of libraries but none of them works. They give me similar error : 
`Unexpected module 'NgAutoCompleteModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation`

This is the library I am trying to use: [ng2-input-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-input-autocomplete)

I have followed all the steps except `add mapping in systemjs config` part. I can't find systemjs file in my project which was created using CLI

Comment: try http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete it works great

Comment: can you show app.module.ts?

Comment: https://justpaste.it/31xwf

Comment: delete PersonnelviewComponent from providers

Comment: I took your advice and replaced it with primeng and it seems to be working. (except ui design) . I will try to check ng2-input-autocomplete after `PersonnelviewComponent` and let you know

Comment: Hey you can have a look at my answer it is working :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** You are not including script file which has autocomplete code (the step that you skipped because you didn't find system.js file)

**Solution:** Since you are using angular cli you need to add this in your `angular-cli.json` file.

there would an array of scripts in your angular-cli.json file add this `node_modules/ng2-input-autocomplete/bundles/ng2-input-autocompleteModule.umd.js` to array.

Something like this ->

```
"scripts": [
            "../node_modules/ng2-input-autocomplete/bundles/ng2-input-autocompleteModule.umd.js",
            ...
            ...
          ],
```

Hope this helps